# How can I change value of an item into array without modify others in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple todolist structure into the state of component. This is an array with two field called 'content' and one called 'done'. I catch click of row item with a simple onClick() function passed from parent to TodoItem childs (like React tutorial suggest):

```
  render() {
   const tthis = this;

   var myList = tthis.state.todos.map(function(todo,index){

      var myOnCLick = function(){
        var newTodo = {content: todo.content, done: !todo.done};
        tthis.state.todos[index] = newTodo;
        tthis.setState({});

      }
      return <Todo key={index} todo={todo} onClick={myOnCLick}/>
   })

   return (
     <ul className="list">
       { myList }
     </ul>
   )
 }
```

This code work without problems, but I don't like so much.
I would find some good solution to change a value of single item in an array. I found that in Immutability helper of React DOC:

> {$set: any} replace the target entirely.

And in a good answer in this forum I saw an example:

```
this.setState({
  todos: update(this.state.todos, {1: {done: {$set: true}}})
```

But I cannot use 1 in my case. I have index which give me the index of clicked todo in todos list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can flip the value of the `done` property on the individual todo object listed in the array in the following way:

```
flipDone(id) {
  let index = Number(id);

  this.setState({
    todos: [
      ...this.state.todos.slice(0, index),
      Object.assign({}, this.state.todos[index], {done: !this.state.todos[index].done}),
      ...this.state.todos.slice(index + 1)
    ]
  });
}
```

Here is a demo: http://codepen.io/PiotrBerebecki/pen/jrdwzB

Full code:

```
class TodoList extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.flipDone = this.flipDone.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      todos: [
        {content: 'Go shopping', done: false},
        {content: 'Walk the dog', done: false},
        {content: 'Wash the dishes', done: false},
        {content: 'Learn React', done: false}
      ]
    };
  }

  flipDone(id) {
    let index = Number(id);

    this.setState({
      todos: [
        ...this.state.todos.slice(0, index),
        Object.assign({}, this.state.todos[index], {done: !this.state.todos[index].done}),
        ...this.state.todos.slice(index + 1)
      ]
    });
  }

  render() {
    const myList = this.state.todos.map((todo, index) => {
      return (
        <Todo key={index} 
              clickHandler={this.flipDone} 
              content={todo.content}
              done={todo.done}
              id={index}
        />
      );
    })

    return (
      <ul className="list">
        {myList}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}


class Todo extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick(event) {
    this.props.clickHandler(event.target.id);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <li>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}
                id={this.props.id}>
          Click me
        </button> --- 
        {String(this.props.done)} --- 
        {this.props.content}      
      </li>
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <TodoList />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Comment: Would you like me to add anything to the above or does it answer your question?

Comment: I never used three point syntax. Your solution work great, but all li in the list call render each time :)

Comment: The 3 point syntax is referred to as spread operator. For example: `let cold = ['autumn', 'winter']; ` `let warm = ['spring', 'summer'];` `console.log([...cold, ...warm])` => `['autumn', 'winter', 'spring', 'summer']` More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator